# Tengo este error en mi vista: "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause" ¿Que hago?

Tags: mysql

Quiero convertir la siguiente consulta en una vista, pero sigo obteniendo el error ya mencionado. Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT C.id_pdmatriz, C.id_proveedor, C.Precio , x.Nombre , p.Nombre
FROM (
SELECT MIN(A.Precio) AS Precio , A.id_pdmatriz
FROM producto A where A.id_proveedor > 0 and A.Estado_id !=5
GROUP BY A.id_pdmatriz) B
JOIN producto C
ON B.Precio = C.Precio
and B.id_pdmatriz = C.id_pdmatriz 
left Join producto_matriz x
ON C.id_pdmatriz = x.id
left Join proveedor p
ON C.id_proveedor = p.id;
```

¿Me pueden ayudar a crear una vista con esta consulta? ¿Porqué obtengo el error?

Comment: El error es lo que figura en el titulo? dice que no podes tener una query en el from. es para crear una vista?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MySql, no es posible incluir una sub consulta en las vistas. Puedes ver mas informacion de las vistas para la [versión 5.7 de MySql en este enlace.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html)

Una **posible solución** es tener un vista independiente para tu sub consulta. La primera vista podría quedar asi:

```
CREATE VIEW Vista1 AS SELECT C.id_pdmatriz, C.id_proveedor, C.Precio , x.Nombre , p.Nombre
FROM Vista2 B
JOIN producto C
ON B.Precio = C.Precio
and B.id_pdmatriz = C.id_pdmatriz 
left Join producto_matriz x
ON C.id_pdmatriz = x.id
left Join proveedor p
ON C.id_proveedor = p.id;
```

La segunda vista quedaria asi:

```
CREATE VIEW Vista2 AS 
SELECT MIN(A.Precio) AS Precio , A.id_pdmatriz
FROM producto A where A.id_proveedor > 0 and A.Estado_id !=5
GROUP BY A.id_pdmatriz
```

Comment: Gracias y como uniría las 2 vistas

Comment: @FmcvMcv lo que hice fue sacar la consulta que tenias en tu FROM y ponerla en una vista aparte, que llame Vista2. Despues, en tu consulta original, sustitui toda esa consulta que tenias en el FROM por una referencia a la vista que se llama Vista2. Asi que basicamente, ya estan "unidas".

Comment: Muchas Gracias kenny